# Oracle - Unique ID fetch using multiple criteria

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement. Can someone please help?

I have this table:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________
UNIQUE_ID   POLICY_SOURCE   POLICY_NUMBER   REFERRED_POLICY_SOURCE  REFERRED_POLICY_NUMBER
1234        custom          AJ123           main                    BH125
1234        main            BH125           custom                  AJ123
2345        dwell           BH125           custom                  HQ658
__________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I now have to obtain the UNIQUE_ID of POLICY_NUMBERs where the POLICY_NUMBERs  are not linked as REFERRED_POLICY_NUMBER individually.

i.e,

- In the table above, the first field, policy AJ123 with UNIQUE_ID 1234 has BH125 as
  REFERRED_POLICY_NUMBER.
- BH125 has two entries, with UNIQUE_ID 1234 and 2345. But BH125 with UNIQUE_ID is linked with AJ123. So that shouldn't be displayed.
- But BH125 with UNIQUE_ID has a different policy HQ658 as
  REFERRED_POLICY_NUMBER. It is this record that should be fetched.

I need to obtain the result in this format:

```
___________________________________________________________
UNIQUE_ID1  POLICY_NUMBER1  UNIQUE_ID2  POLICY_NUMBER2
1234        AJ123           2345        BH125
___________________________________________________________
```

To be short, **two are more policies linked but with different UNIQUE_ID**s.

What I have tried till now:

```
SELECT UNIQUE_ID, POLICY_NUMBER, REFERRED_POLICY_NUMBER FROM TABLE WHERE REFERRED_POLICY_NUMBER IN (SELECT POLICY_NUMBER FROM TABLE);
```

I have obtained records where REFERRED_POLICY_NUMBER in POLICY_NUMBER. Dumbstruck on how to obtain the UNIQUE_ID of all those.

Any help would be much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT table1.UNIQUE_ID AS UNIQUE_ID1, 
       table1.POLICY_NUMBER AS POLICY_NUMBER1,
       table2.UNIQUE_ID AS UNIQUE_ID2, 
       table2.POLICY_NUMBER AS POLICY_NUMBER2
FROM mainTable table1
     JOIN mainTable table2
     ON table1.REFERRED_POLICY_NUMBER= table2.POLICY_NUMBER
        AND table2.REFERRED_POLICY_NUMBER <> table1.POLICY_NUMBER
```

Comment: What is POLICY_ID Minh?

Comment: NUMBER and ID got me confused :). Fixed